# probability expected winnings per lottery question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, conditional-probability, lotteries

I am trying to solve this problem but I'm a little stuck:

You and your friends decide to make a lottery with $n$ tickets, where each ticket has a number between $1$ and $n$, and each ticket is unique. Each ticket is $\$5$, and the lottery works in the following way. Once all $n$ tickets have been purchased, a number $x$ is selected uniformly at random between $1$ and $n$ and all the money is split equally between people with tickets less than $x$. That way, if $x=1$ is selected, you and your friends get to keep the prize pool.

1. What is your expected winnings per lottery as the organizer?

So what I did was make 2 cases. The first case is when $x = 1$ and the organizer keeps all the money, and the second case is where $x > 1$ and the organizer gets no money:

Case 1: $x = 1$

$P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$
organizer gets $5n$ money
$\frac{1}{n}(5n) = 5$

Case 2: $x > 1$

$P(X > 1) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$
organizer gets no money
$\left(1- \frac{1}{n}\right)(0) = 0$

From there I add the 2 equations and I get that the expected winnings per lottery as the organizer is $5 but the problem is I'm supposed to be getting an equation, the answer shouldn't be a number but I don't know where I'm going wrong. I would really appreciate any advice!

Comment: Given the stated problem, your answer is correct. Initially the assuption would be that the answer will depend on $n$, but the calculation, using equations, shows that it doesn't. That's not your fault, $E(L_n)=5$ is a valid answer. Of course, you might have misunderstood the problem from the source you got it from. Maybe the question was about expected winning for a player?

Comment: @Ingix The full question asks you about both. Also thank you for your help!
                                                                                                                                       1. What is your expected winnings per lottery as the organizer?
2. What is your expected winnings if you purchase a ticket?

Comment: Now it makes more sense, as the answer to question 1 can help you find the answer for question 2 in an easier way than "brute calculation".

Answer (score 0):

The answer and derivation are correct. As revealed in the comments, the source of the question continues with asking about expected winnings for a player, to which this question is a stepping stone.

Answer (score 0):

The pot is $5n$

You have correctly found expected winnings for the organiser, $\mathbb{E}[X] = 5$

If the organiser doesn't get the pot, the "players" must, and by symmetry, each will earn the same on an average

Thus expected earning for a player $=\Large\frac{5n-5}{n}$

Comment: I read it as you need to be strictly less than $n$ to win.  So, $1$ is a good ticket but $n$ has no hope of winning.  Should it be $k < n$?

Comment: @badjohn: The rules are quirky, but actually over a period, each person will hold each ticket (including #1 and #n) an equal number of times

Comment: I view it as a one-off but the OP is not clear.

Comment: @badjohn: Even for a one-off, we have to consider the weighted average

Comment: I see what you mean.  You are considering the position of the players before they know their number.  I was thinking of after.  If you get $1$ then you have a good chance.  If you get $n$ then you can immediately throw away your ticket.